# Can not load .sql file into mysql (using cmd) - syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am working through the first lesson of an introduction to mysql course, and 
there is a file I need to load.

1. I opened cmd.
2. I connected using the command: `mysql -u root -p`
3. as the lesson instructions are telling me to do, I used the command:

   `mysql>mysql -u root < C:/temp/imdb_small.sql;`

and I got this error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root < C:/temp/imdb_small.sql' at line 1`

how can I fix this?

Comment: at the `mysql>` prompt, we can enter `source C:/temp/imdb_small.sql` to tell the MySQL client to read a file and execute the contents as SQL statements. (We run the `mysql` from the OS command prompt to execute the MySQL command line client. The default for mysql command line client is to run in interactive mode, prompting the user for input with `mysql>` prompt. Here we can enter SQL statements e.g. `USE test;`,  `SELECT NOW();` etc. It's also possible to run the MySQL command  line client in a non-interactive mode, we can provide the SQL statements to execute.

Comment: At the OS command prompt `C:\>`  we can do  `mysql -u root -p < C:/temp/imdb_small.sql`  which will cause the MySQL command line client to execute (prompt for a password), connect to the database, and execute the SQL statements found in the specified file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "mysql>" is a prompt showing you that you are now operating within the mysql command environment, so you don't need to type in another 'mysql' command. This is what the error message is telling you.

Anyway, after connecting to mysql, I believe the command to execute the contents of an sql file is "source", so you would enter at the mysql prompt:

```
source C:/temp/imdb_small.sql;
```

So it would appear on screen, with the prompt:

```
mysql> source C:/temp/imdb_small.sql;
```

Alternatively, if you dont want to enter the interactive mysql command environemnt, from the shell just type a SINGLE mysql command to execute commands form the sql file:

```
mysql -u root < C:/temp/imdb_small.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you need to "load" the file, I believe you mean importing it.

The command you referenced, is meant to be used *before* logging in. Based on the `mysql>` prompt, you are *already* logged in therefore don't need `mysql -u root -p` again. On top of that, the command you are using looks incorrect. You need to specify the database name you want to import to.

```
mysql> database_name < C:/temp/imdb_small.sql;
```